# Changing character colour from input

Tags: c#, textbox, richtextbox

I'm trying to change the colour of a character if the input from the text box matches the one in the rich text box.

```
char key = e.KeyChar;
for(int i = 0; i < rchtxtbox.Text.Length; i++)
{
    char currentLetter = rchtxtbox.Text[i];
    if (key == currentLetter)
    {
        rchtxtbox.SelectionStart = 0;
        rchtxtbox.SelectionLength = 1;
        rchtxtbox.SelectionColor = Color.White;
        rchtxtbox.SelectionBackColor = Color.LightGreen;
    }
}
```

It only highlights the current letter if it does matches. An example is if the word in the rich text box is "balloon" and the input first typed is "b", it matches and changes colour but if the next letter was added "ba" the function stops working and does not change colour. Other alternatives I have tried ended up changing the colours of all matched characters. I want to be able to colour it character by character if it matches, is there a way to do this easily?

Comment: You need to correctly set the `rchtxtbox.SelectionStart' to appropriate index of the character. In your code the selection start point is zero, so it will always highlight the first character

Comment: I tried changing the value to the i value but this highlights all the matches. Example if I had "plop", if I typed "p", it would highlight both the start and end p's

Comment: Ok, then get the last keyed character from the textbox, get its index and match the same index character from the richtextbox, if matched highlight that one instead of running the loop

Comment: Which event handler has this code?

Comment: the keypress event of the text box

Comment: Could you possible add the entire method in which this block of code is executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's how you can achieve this. I have used KeyUp event instead of keypress

```cs
private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {           
    if (textBox1.TextLength == 0) { return; }

    int index;
    index = textBox1.TextLength - 1;
    char key = textBox1.Text[index];

    if (rchtxtbox.TextLength > index  && rchtxtbox.Text[index] == key) {   
        if (rchtxtbox.Text[index] == key) {
                rchtxtbox.SelectionStart = index;
                rchtxtbox.SelectionLength = 1;
                rchtxtbox.SelectionColor = Color.White;
                rchtxtbox.SelectionBackColor = Color.LightGreen;
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure you replace `textBox1` above with the name of your textbox

Comment: I noticed that at times it misses out highlighting some characters. This could be due to the KeyUp event. However, if I moved the code into a keypress event, it does not like the index?

Comment: great. Did you make any change in the code fix I suggested or it worked as it is?

Comment: As it was in the keyup event, it stuttered slightly where it would not highlight a matched character. This could have been due to the keyup, so i just simply moved it to the keypress event instead but it didn't like the index therefore I just left it as the .TextLength without any subtraction to the index and changed the key to KeyChar instead. Thanks for the help again!

Comment: You are welcome. Good to know that your issue is resolved

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your questions correctly, the issue is just that you are only ever selecting the first character for highlight.

You should be setting **SelectionStart** to **i**, so it selects and highlights the character you are comparing against:

```
rchtxtbox.SelectionStart = i;
```

**Edit:**

After thinking about what you're trying to do, I think you have a rich text box with text in it.  You also have a text box that the user is typing into.  As the user types into the text box, you want to highlight that text in the rich text box.  Correct?

Here is a simple example, although this doesn't account for multiple occurrences of the text being found.

```
        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int idx = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(textBox1.Text);

        if (idx > -1)
        {
            richTextBox1.SelectionStart = idx;
            richTextBox1.SelectionLength = textBox1.Text.Length;
            richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.White;
            richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.LightGreen;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I tried this and it takes the input and highlights all the correct matches in the rich text box when ideally i only want the currentPosition highlighted - if correct.